# Modeling multiple, replicated consumers with Jetstream

Tags: nats.io, nats-jetstream

I am trying to model my problem using NATS and Jetstream.
Previously, I was using a plain MQTT broker to move messages between my services but we will be requiring temporal decoupling the consumers from the producers.
The scenario goes like this:

- we have multiple service producing events on an `activity-log/{entity}/{operation}`
- those events are consumed by at least another service that persists the message onto a database to provide querying capabilities on all the logs. This service is, hence, subscribed to `activity-log.#` messages
- the service that persists the messages is containerized and running with multiple instances. We use MQTT5 shared subscriptions (similar to Core NATS queue groups) to "load-balance" handling of those messages
- additionally, there may be other consumers (or none) of the same message, performing a completely different action. Those services are subscribed to a subset of all the activity logs and each extra subscriber will filter the messages by the topic
- those consumers are also "load-balanced". That is the message will be handling by one out of several replicas
- those ex

What would be the best way to model my problem?

My initial idea was to have a stream for this topic `activity-log.>`.
For that stream have a pull consumer consuming all the messages (the equivalent of the multiple replicas subscribed to `activity-log/#`) and then other pull consumers with topic filtering.
However that does not seem to be possible because those consumers topics cannot overlap.

I can see the [example from the documentation](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/jetstream/consumers/example_configuration) to be similar to what I want to accomplish but push consumers are used.
I heard push consumers are not the way to go forward (can't say why, though).